# List which applications are subscribing to a multicast group in Windows

Tags: windows-10, udp, multicast

I've been looking for way to list what processes/applications on my host are subscribing to what multicast addresses.

Through the command line, I can issue

```
netsh interface ip show joins
```

which lists all interfaces and the multicast addresses are joined by my host:

```
Interface 19: Wi-Fi

Scope       References  Last  Address
----------  ----------  ----  ---------------------------------
0                    2  Yes   228.5.6.7
```

From what I understand, the "references" column shows the number of processes assigned to each group. In the above excerpt, I've started two processes on my host to listen to this address. If I terminate them both, this column instead shows zero, as expected.

For sure, Windows must keep track of these in order to deliver incoming datagrams. I wonder if there is any tool which lists what applications are listening to this group (PID and/or executables)? Also what ports are used would be of interest.